# Customize Django Admin, Order and place of model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a Django project
in this project i have app a with model A and app b with model B.

```
# a/models.py
class A(models.Model):
    pass
```

```
# b.models.py
class B(models.Model):
    pass
```

So i see Model A under section of app a and same for Model B.

But I want to change this placement
because from the first of project I was bad in layout.

notice: I've tried putting BModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin) in admin file of app a and it has not worked.

please tell me an absolute answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use proxy models:

```
# b.models.py
class B(models.Model):
    pass

class ProxyB(B):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
        app_label = 'a'
```

and then you need to register proxy model in a.admin or in b.admin.

```
#a.admin
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import A
from b.models import ProxyB


@admin.register(A)
class AAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


@admin.register(ProxyB)
class BAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Comment: should i enter anything inside proxy model?
or just use it?

Comment: nope, just Meta class as in example, all fields and other stuff are  inherited from B model